# SQL Server Native Client error "A trigger returned a resultset"

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

Need help

I have try firstly to use

```
FDTable.insert
  ///code;
FDTable.post
```

and i got error :[firedac][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active

I have try secondly use Array DML

```
    FDQuery1.Params.ArraySize := QTE;
     for i := 1 to QTE do begin
     FDQuery1.ParamByName('REFBON').Value:=REFBON;
     ......
     FDQuery1.ParamByName('PUBON').AsInteger:=PUBON;

   end;
   FDQuery1.Execute(QTE, 0);
```

I have got same error [firedac][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active

Please I need your help

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The problem is related to a **trigger**, which is automatically executed on the **server** when an event (insert, delete, update) happens. It has nothing to do with your code, necessarily. Talk to your DBA about the triggers that may be in place for your table.

Comment: there are no trigger on the server my previouse application work with bde (delphi 7) Here I migrate to firedac with xe5 and I have this problem.

Comment: There are no trigger on the server. My previous application worked with bde (delphi 7).  Here I migrate to firedac with xe5 and I have this problem. the table have actually 3 258 533 lines  but no problem with bde delphi in this fonctionnality. I have another thing who doesn't work in bde and i decide to migrate to firedac with delphi XE5.

Comment: Have you tried to do an INSERT directly on the SQL Server Management Studio ?. To check if you get the same error ?. Because this seriously looks as a server problem and not a bug on your application. It would take you just a minute to verify it or rule it out.

Comment: I have do an insert directly on the Sql Server Management Studio but I have no error. When i use my application on BDE with delphi 7 I have no problem. My problem is with firedac on delphi XE5.

Comment: I will try to reinstall SQL Server tomorrow  maybe  it will resolve the problem. I will come tomorrow for the result.

Comment: The BDE didn't use the SQL Native Client 10.0, because it didn't exist when the BDE was last updated. This is a different error that you may not have gotten before because you were using a different client library. The error message is **very clear** that the problem is related to a trigger.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have create a test trigger but I have forget to delete. resolved

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server no longer supports triggers that return results.

[https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186337(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186337(v=sql.110).aspx)